# Strip Variant from Locale in Python?

Tags: python, locale

When users make a request to my server they send along with it the locale from their browser so we can serve them in the language they prefer. For most US English users we get a the locale as `en-US` as expected. However, some are sending a locale as `en-US-posix` or `en-US-u-va-posix`. We'd like to just take the en-US version of that. Obviously we could just find-replace `-posix` and `-u-va-posix`, but we'd also like to do this with other languages without looking into each locale and making that decision manually.

So we really just want to strip out the variant of any locale and get the simplified locale. The problem is, it's not consistent between locales where the variant is placed. In some languages the variant comes between the language and the country.

I have yet to find a library that can parse all the types of locales we are seeing as well. babel, for example, didn't recognize 120 of the 555 locales we've collected.

The native python `locale` module seems to recognize all of the locales at least, but i don't see a way of pulling out just the language/country given something like `en-US-u-va-posix`.

How can I strip the variant from any locale in python?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good question. I don't know of any metadata in `locale` that can help you, but a quick and dirty solution might be to use a regular expression, and perhaps build exceptions as you need them. For example:

```
import re

def get_short_locale(locale_name):
    return re.match(r'^([a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+)(.*)$', locale_name)[1]
```

This is prone to errors with complex locales, like "iu-Cans-CA" and "iu-Latn-CA", but if you need to support those, you could add exceptions until someone comes up with a more resilient solution.